# What's the best way to write synchronous code using async libraries

Tags: sql, node.js, asynchronous, ldap

I've been asked to help write some server-side scripts that update calendars, contacts, e-mail and other company services from other internal services for compliance reasons. The code needs to access the LDAP server, an SQL database and e-mail server, compile and merge information in a peculiar way and then go through information in the calendars, contacts and update those depending on what's there and in the LDAP/SQL databases. This needs to be done a couple of times a day, so performance isn't particularly important.

I wanted to try to use node.js for this and after spending a few days with it, I'm having second thoughts as to whether node.js is the right tool to do this. I'm an old school programmer, have C, C++, Unix, SQL, LDAP, TCP/IP in my small finger but I've learned JavaScript/Node.js in a few days out of curiosity.

I use LDAP, SQL and CalDav/CardDAV modules from npm. These are based on Promises.

Thanks to promises, the code is super ugly, unreadable and buggy if there's any kind of network problem. Things that are very easy in classic language such as C or Java are suddenly a massive headache, such as the fact that (say) LDAP information will arrive at a later stage, but there's no point in async operations as nothing can be done in parallel while waiting for those. This pattern repeats itself throughout the code - async operations complicating matters incredibly for zero benefit. It's incredibly difficult to calculate any sort of aggregate values and apply them elsewhere when using these async functions.

My question is this: is there a simple way to invoke async functions that will simply return the value instead of invoking callbacks?

Comment: "*is there a simple way to invoke async functions that will simply return the value instead of invoking callbacks?*" yes: `await`. Why aren't you using it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the vast majority of I/O calls in Node.js are asynchronous. So if you're totally uncomfortable with this, it may not be the right fit for what you're doing.

It is a (IMHO) brilliant language, and you'll find it more comfortable to use as you get used to it.

However, you can write code using Promises that *looks* very much like synchronous code using the [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax. I find this much easier to deal with compared to using lot's of .thens and .catch.

You can also use try and catch in this context and it will work as you would expect.

This makes for much cleaner, more readable code.

Most Node.js modules support Promises, for those that don't you can often convert functions to returning a Promise rather than expecting a callback to be passed.

**NB: Don't forget to *await* calls to async. functions. I find this is one of the most common errors one makes when using this syntax.**

For example:

```js
function callApi() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({ status: 'ok'}), 500))
}

async function testApi() {
    try { 
        console.log("callApi: Calling function...");
        let result = await callApi();
        console.log("callApi result:", result);
    } catch (err) { 
        console.error("callApi: Error:", err.message);
    }
}

testApi();
```

Then a further example to show catching an error (say the api fails for some reason):

```js
function callApi() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Api error")), 500))
}

async function testApi() {
    try { 
        console.log("callApi: Calling function...");
        let result = await callApi();
        console.log("callApi result:", result);
    } catch (err) { 
        console.error("callApi: Error:", err.message);
    }
}

testApi();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't get your sample doesn't to work. If I change 100 to 5000, the function returns "ok" immediately instead of waiting for 5 seconds.

Comment: Apologies, I had a typo (swapping the params in setTimeout), should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It does indeed work, I'll try to see how to use a npm js library that returns promises without the async nightmare.

Comment: I'd play around a little with this pattern, you should be a ble to avoid callback hell this way.  I think you'll find that Node.js is actually great for your application.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript - no. Waiting async call to complete would block the only thread and so would stop all the work, and so such waiting is not implemented.
But there exists async/await mechanism - syntactic sugar over asynchronous calls, which mimics synchronous calls.